# How to downgrade IE version?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp

I am developing a web application and it needs to be tested in Internet Explorer 7. I have IE 8 installed in my computer.

When I try to install IE 7 , the setup breaks, giving "Setup cannot continue. A more recent version of IE is found in your computer".

How do I install IE 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use IE Tester http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

> IETester is a free (both for personal and professional usage) WebBrowser that allows you to have the rendering and javascript engines of IE10 preview, IE9, IE8, IE7 IE 6 and IE5.5 on Windows 7, Vista and XP, as well as the installed IE in the same process.